# How to show dynamic tabs view using functional component in react native

Tags: react-native

I am using API response to create a dynamic tab, but they give me the error.

TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'getMerchantCategoryList.map')

below is my code:-

```
 <Tab.Navigator
  screenOptions={{
    tabBarLabelStyle: {fontSize: 12, fontFamily: 'Poppins-Medium'},
    tabBarItemStyle: {width: 'auto'},
    lazy: true,
    lazyPreloadDistance: 3,
    tabBarIndicatorStyle: {backgroundColor: Colors.bright_sky_blue},
    tabBarScrollEnabled: true,
    swipeEnabled: true,
  }}>
  {getMerchantCategoryList.map(subCategory => (
    <Tab.Screen
      key={subCategory.pcmsc_id}
      name={subCategory.pcmsc_cat_name}
      component={MerchantSubCategoryItem}
      options={{tabBarLabel: subCategory.pcmsc_cat_name}}
      initialParams={{subCategory}}
    />
  ))}
</Tab.Navigator>
```

Comment: I think the best solution is make scrollview and list all your tabs thier and show data according to active tabs if tabs are going beyond the screen so.If I get chance I will update you with the code.

Comment: are using react navigation for your purpose ??